# Can HTML controls <input type="radio" /> or <input type="checkbox" /> be used as lists for a database source?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net

I'm a C#/VB developer trying to migrate away from aspx and web forms towards HTML.

I'm trying to do this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" id="rb" runat="server" />
```

**C#**

```
DataTable dt = clsMyClass.GetItemTable();
rb.DataSource = dt;
rb.DataValueField = "ItemID";
rb.DataTextField = "ItemName";
rb.DataBind();
```

Thanks.

Comment: *In Short*: No. No equivalent. *In Long*: "*... trying to migrate away from aspx and web forms towards HTML ...*": while you are at it, you also need to learn the difference between a server-side framework and raw HTML.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to bind these elements with contents from your database or simply trying to add some text...

You can make a function in your codebehind to catch the data from your database and simply write it to your input controls by using response.write methods...

**UPDATE**

Hey!!! how about a function in codebehind like ....

```
public  string getTheValueFromDataBase()
{
  string abc = "";
  abc =  "text from database over here...";
  return abc;
}
```

**IN HTML PAGE**

```
<input type="radio" /><%Response.Write(getTheValueFromDataBase()); %>
```

Comment: That's what I'm trying to to do. I'm trying to make the equivalent of an asp:RadioButtonList.

Could I ask for an example please?

Comment: What I am understanding from your question is that you are trying to display some text besides the input radio. The text must come from database.... Right!!!

Comment: Pretty much. If I can attach a matching ID to the control as well I'd know where to go from there.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely helps. I've updated my question to better explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @user2078938: Are you trying to create a list of radios or just a single radio.

Comment: A list of radios, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Now, If you are not using the "runat=server" tag for the radiobuttonlist control then, you have to loop through the html control, get the count of the number of radio buttons from the database and use the for loop in the HTML page inside the <% %>.

Comment: Cool, I'll give that a shot. Cheers for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can use the controls provided by the Microsoft ASP.NET Web Forms to control what and how the User interacts with the Application that you're providing him with.

Actaully what those controls provide you is that you Validate the data on the server side as well as client side. The keyword, `runat="server"` is used to tell the server that this Element should be handled on the Server.

If you want to redesign your application you can do that too. Instead of doing anything, just simply use your own Controls.

```
<input type="text" onchange="function()" />
```

In the JavaScript you can handle the events on that element.

```
function () {
   /* some validations */
}
```

`runat="server"` is just to ensure that whenever the control's value is changed or any other particular functions are triggered the server would execute some method to take control of that.

Similarly, if you're not using Web Forms. You can create your own custom Controls and your own custom events to handle all the methods and events.

For example, if you have this control

```
<input type="text" name="myName" />
```

jQuery would be handy in this

```
$('input[name=myName]').change(function () {
   alert('Hi, ' + $(this).value);
}
```

This way, once a user changes the value, he would get an alert for **Hi, [name_of_user]**. If I were to write Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan, it would pop up

**Hi, Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan**.

Now let's give the whole form control. Sample form is

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="text" name="myName" />
   <input type="text" name="id" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

jQuery would be

```
$('form').submit(function () {
   /* send data to server */
}
```

On the server side, handle those fields and then save them.